# How to open index.php file and displayed like webpage on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, web, html

I would like to ask a question. I started off to create my website by using Notepad(default program provided by Windows). When i have added some html code and css into this `index.php`, I can open it on `google chrome` and `firefox` that displaying like a `webpage`. But, when it comes to `IE (internet explorer)`, it asks whether to save or open the file(open like notepad instead of showing as webpage). Is there any setting i need to do before i can successfully display the file like a web page on IE? Any solution?

Comment: Post your PHP file (a sample that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: Hey Stuart Siegler, it's just a normal html file. I just named the file with `php` extension.

Comment: If it is an html file then name it `index.html` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file

Select **open with** and choose **default program**, and select IE

or, if **open with** is not an option, select **open**, and choose **select a program to open with** and select IE